# `package_name': 'package' not found in aapt output (RuntimeError) while running calabash in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, calabash-android

I got the error response **package_name': 'package' not found in aapt output (RuntimeError)** when I run the calabash-android in docker file. Can anyone please tell me why it is happening like this. The full error response is pasting below.

```
sh: 1: /usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: not found
/usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:18:in `package_name': 'package' not found in aapt output (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in calabash_build'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:38:in `chdir'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:38:in `block in calabash_build'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:37:in `calabash_build'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:106:in `build_test_server_if_needed'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:in `calabash_run'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/bin/calabash-android:84:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/calabash-android:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/calabash-android:22:in `<main>'
```

Since I haven't integrated calabash-android in docker before could not figure out the exact issue. All kinda helps are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue raises since the android dependencies are not installed.

I fixed the issue by installing the dependencies. And the command to install the dependencies is `apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev`

Comment: Please let me know the reason while downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message, it looks like the android tools are not installed in your container.

Comment: Thanks jmoody for your helping hand. But I have done this command "RUN echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-19.1.0,android-19,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-analytics_sdk_v2 --no-ui --force -a
" to install the dependencies